# In univariate logistic regression, does the scale of values affect the predicted "risk" at a particular value of the independent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, logit, univariate

I have many datasets representing different populations. Each dataset contains values of an independent variable along with (0/1) representing the occurrence of an undesirable event. I analysed each of the datasets separately by using univariate logistic regression.

The goal was to calculate and compare the risk at a particular value in all the datasets. I was then able to put the different populations in order based the risk predicted at the same value V.

The problem is that I found that the risk calculated has quite a strong negative correlation with the maximum values in the datasets. In other words, the population X with the lowest risk happens to have the largest maximum in its dataset compared with the other populations.

I am now concerned that my conclusion (i.e. the population X has the lowest risk at value V) may only be a result of having the largest independent value in its dataset, and not because of any other factor.

Is my concern correct?

Comment: By the way, all datasets have roughly the same median value.

Answer (score 1):

A couple points:

1) To find the risk of the undesirable event, you do not need logistic regression. It's just a proportion. Logistic regression is about the relationship between the IV and risk

2) To compare the risk of the event across data sets, you can use chi-square tests.

3) If you want to get estimates of the effect of group membership on risk then you should combine the data sets and run a logistic regression with event as the DV and both group and the original IV as IVs. If you want to see if the relationship  is different across groups, then you should add the interaction between these two.

Comment: For example, in [1], a formula derived from the univariate logistic regression was used to calculate to calculate the value of an independent variable at a given Acceptable Risk Level. So, why exactly I should not use it to find the risk? Is it fundamentally wrong?


[1] R. Bender, “Quantitative Risk Assessment in Epidemiological Studies Investigating Threshold Effects,” biometrical journal, vol.41, no. 3, pp. 305-319, 1999.

Comment: Because you don't need to; that is for relating the IV to the risk.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your responses. The problem is that I have been working based on this for over a month now. So, I will throw my work out only if it is fundamentally wrong. If it is only about (you don't need to), I would obviously prefer not to throw it out:)

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you did and why; and what you wrote about it, it's hard to say. But it does sound like you've been going about this the wrong way.